# Error with promise rejections while using bulkDelete

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So upon using the [.bulkDelete()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) method, which deletes messages from a channel, I get this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
>
> (node:11720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) (node:11720) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Here is my code:

```
//delete the given amount of message + 1 for the sent message
let msgToDelete = parseInt(args[1]) + 1;

//filter messages too old and delete unfiltered messages
msg.channel.bulkDelete(msgToDelete, true)
  .then(deleted => {
    if (deleted.size <= 1) return;
    msg.channel.send(`deleted ${args[1]} messages.`)
      .then(m => m.delete(2500))
      .catch(err => console.error);
  }).catch(err => msg.channel.send(err));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your catch has code which is throwing the exception which is not handled as it is occuring inside the catch block.

It is worth putting a catch at the global level and catch the error and log it.

Also, regarding the way you are chaining your promises, you could simplify that like this

```
//delete the given amount of message + 1 for the sent message
let msgToDelete = parseInt(args[1]) + 1;

//filter messages too old and delete unfiltered messages
msg.channel.bulkDelete(msgToDelete, true)
  .then(deleted => {
    if (deleted.size <= 1) return;
    return msg.channel.send(`deleted ${args[1]} messages.`);
  })
  .then(m => m.delete(2500))
  .catch(err => msg.channel.send(err));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response however after correcting my code, I get the same error `DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message` and `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.`. Would you have any idea?

Comment: worth putting a catch to your `msg.channel.send(err)` call to see what error you are getting. basically `msg.channel.send(err).catch(err => console.log(err)`

Comment: I added the catch block and I still get the same error

Comment: do you have some other code as well which might be raising exception. Have you tried putting console statements and see till where the execution is going?

Comment: so I checked the code and put a console.log("here") statement after the final catch block and it prints here and then sends the error, PS: I do not have any promises else than the ones in the code I sent.

Comment: if you have put it outside, it will be executed first as it is outside the promise chain. you need put different console inside each then and catch and see where the error is originating from.

Comment: nothing does it I've added console.logs inside every catch block and the error just goes off without triggering any catch console.log.

Comment: is it possible to put the full code somewhere? may be github? I can have a look

Comment: sure here https://github.com/AlexSimpler/DiscordBot/blob/master/commands/utility/purge.js

Comment: can you see it?

Comment: yup..looking in to it.

Comment: ok and thanks again for looking into my problem, I really appreciate it :D!

Comment: try this - https://gist.github.com/montumodi/e2a1434085a95cb4234f8c875fb5135a

I have converted it to use async/await and a global try catch. I have also create a new function called handleError which you can call whenever and wherver you want to log error and do async operation inside it. hope fully this gives you an idea.

Comment: thank you for your code however it still logs the same error, I think it might be an error with the bulkDelete function itself, it's really not normal.